# I cant connect mysql server to EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, remote-access

Steps I took based on research :

- created free tier amazon instance and connected through putty
- created a user inside MySQL workbench with all the privileges as root is not
  letting me connect remotely on the 127.0.0.1
- changed the inbound rule in EC2 to add MySQL port
- installed mySQL on my EC2 instance
- checked the MySQL file in windows and cant find bind_address to change the
  connection  to all IP instead of 127.0.0.1

  Question :
- Where do I find the mysql.cnf file to comment out bind-address
- what steps/tools  do I use to achieve my goal of connecting local MySQL workbench to connect to EC2 instance
  -and the next goal of connecting local MySQL workbench to MySQL in EC2.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you ssh into the instance, can you connect to the mysql using `mysql` command line?

Comment: I'm a little confused... Is the Amazon EC2 instance Linux or Windows? Are you wanting to connect from your own computer to MySQL _directly_ (for which you opened the Security Group), or are you wanting to connect via an SSH Tunnel (as suggested by the error messsage)? Or, do you have 2 x Amazon EC2 instances (as suggested by the two different IP addresses shown in your pictures)?